# Dynamic search and filtering in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, filtering, search-box

Currently I am experimenting with dynamic search bars and filtering in Excel. 
I have found a nice tutorial that uses a table and Active-X text box. I have recreated it and surely it works. My problem however is that it only takes into account one column. Now, I have created another table and another search bar, thinking that it would work just as fine, however, for some reason it does not.
Here is the problem:
The data set looks like this;
[image]
Searching for cells containing "1" in "addr1"(works normal):
[image]
Searching for cells containing "1" in "addr2"(does not work):
[image]

I have tried setting the format to Text, general, number etc. but nothing seems to have any effect. The second search should list the cells containing "123" as well but it doesn't.

VBA Code in the Sheet:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("address1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*"  & [A1] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("address2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & [B1] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Anybody has any solution?

My sample file can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4hpsczrhjbe2is/searchbar.xlsm?dl=0

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: You should post the code assigned to these textboxes instead of sending a link for download...

Comment: Thank you, forgot about that. Edited the entry.

Answer (score 1):

In the second code:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("address2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & [B1] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

You should change `Field:=1` to `Field:=2`, otherwise you'll be searching the content at `TextBox2_Change`at `addr1` column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing for now is that the filter `"*1*"` will only match strings, not numbers. Even if you format your cells as `Text`, the *already entered numbers* will be still parsed as numbers; they wont be converted to strings. You have two ways to enter a number as string:

- enter it in to the cell *after* you had formatted it as `Text`
- enter it preceded with some `'` (single quote). i.e. `'123`. This would force Excel to take it as a string, even if the format of the cell is `General`.

For the time being you may write a simple macro to convert all you table's data into strings and proceed from there.

Finally I don't understand why you define a different table for each of the three adjacent columns. You should make only one table with three columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two samples.  See the images below to get a sense of how these work.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/1ozjpza6zx0gav8/FastFilter.xls

http://www.mediafire.com/file/u7la5pdx8qtxzm5/Filter_using_Event_Code.xlsb

[image]

[image]